# SharedPreferences not fire onStart when changed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have wrote a app for fetch the earthquake data from USGS, I would like to add preference change for the user who are want to check with different mag level. However, the onStart do not fire when the preference is change. Please suggest me how to revised the code

```
public class EarthquakeFragment extends Fragment{
public EarthquakeFragment(){
}

ListView listView;
private EarthquakeAdapter eAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.earthquake_fragment, container, false);

    eAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<EarthquakeInfo>());
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(eAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            EarthquakeInfo currentEarthquake = eAdapter.getItem(position);
            String url = currentEarthquake.getUrl();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // Start the AsyncTask to fetch the earthquake data
    EarthquakeAsyncTask task = new EarthquakeAsyncTask();
    task.execute();
    return rootView;
}


/**
 * {@link AsyncTask} to perform the network request on a background thread, and then
 * update the UI with the list of earthquakes in the response.
 *
 * AsyncTask has three generic parameters: the input type, a type used for progress updates, and
 * an output type. Our task will take a String URL, and return an Earthquake. We won't do
 * progress updates, so the second generic is just Void.
 *
 * We'll only override two of the methods of AsyncTask: doInBackground() and onPostExecute().
 * The doInBackground() method runs on a background thread, so it can run long-running code
 * (like network activity), without interfering with the responsiveness of the app.
 * Then onPostExecute() is passed the result of doInBackground() method, but runs on the
 * UI thread, so it can use the produced data to update the UI.
 */
private class EarthquakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<EarthquakeInfo>> {

    /**
     * This method runs on a background thread and performs the network request.
     * We should not update the UI from a background thread, so we return a list of
     * {@link EarthquakeInfo}s as the result.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<EarthquakeInfo> doInBackground(String... urls) {


        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String maglevel = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_mag_key), "");

            final String BASE_URL= "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "format";
            final String ORDER_PARAM = "orderby";
            final String START_PARAM = "starttime";
            final String END_PARAM = "endtime";
            final String MINMAG_PARAM = "minmag";
            String format = "geojson";
            String order = "time";
            String start = "2016-01-01";
            String end = "2016-07-28";
            String minmag = maglevel;

            Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(ORDER_PARAM, order)
                    .appendQueryParameter(START_PARAM, start)
                    .appendQueryParameter(END_PARAM, end)
                    .appendQueryParameter(MINMAG_PARAM, minmag)
                    .build();
            String url = buildUri.toString();


        // Don't perform the request if there are no URLs, or the first URL is null.
        if (url == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<EarthquakeInfo> result = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(url);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * This method runs on the main UI thread after the background work has been
     * completed. This method receives as input, the return value from the doInBackground()
     * method. First we clear out the adapter, to get rid of earthquake data from a previous
     * query to USGS. Then we update the adapter with the new list of earthquakes,
     * which will trigger the ListView to re-populate its list items.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<EarthquakeInfo> data) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        onStart();
        eAdapter.clear();

        // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            eAdapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Many thanks!!!!!

Comment: Do you want the `onStart()` event of your activity to be executed when the value of a shared preference changes?

Comment: yes. this what I want to do

Comment: Dont know why someone will downvote without commenting what their problem is with the question. This should be stopped.

Comment: Thanks Talha for what you say ;)

Answer (score 0):

Listening for changes on `SharedPreferences` doesn't work that way.

For that you need to implement [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html:)

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
                           SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        // your stuff here
    }
};
```

In your `PreferenceActivity`, ie make it a member of your `PreferenceActivity` class and then do `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(spChanged)` in the `PreferenceActivity.onCreate()` method.

Comment: Thanks lalongooo ;) I will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem finally.

I call the fetch data method on the onResume. Since I cannot fetch data with empty on AsyncTask, it will cause NullPointExection. So I make I default url for execute the AsyncTask. After that, I add the SharePreference at onResume. After that the problem is solved.

Here is my code.

```
public class EarthquakeFragment extends Fragment{

public EarthquakeFragment(){
}

ListView listView;
EarthquakeAdapter eAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    String defaultUrl = getActivity().getString(R.string.default_link);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.earthquake_fragment, container, false);

    eAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<EarthquakeInfo>());
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(eAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            EarthquakeInfo currentEarthquake = eAdapter.getItem(position);
            String url = currentEarthquake.getUrl();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // Start the AsyncTask to fetch the earthquake data
    EarthquakeAsyncTask task = new EarthquakeAsyncTask();
    task.execute(defaultUrl);
    return rootView;
}

private void updateEarthquake() {
    EarthquakeAsyncTask earthquakeTask = new EarthquakeAsyncTask();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String maglevel = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_mag_key), getString(R.string.pref_mag_6));
    String startTime = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.start_key), getString(R.string.pref_time_2016));
    String sortby= preferences.getString(getString(R.string.sort_key), getString(R.string.pref_sortby_time));

    final String BASE_URL= "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?";
    final String FORMAT_PARAM = "format";
    final String ORDER_PARAM = "orderby";
    final String START_PARAM = "starttime";
    final String END_PARAM = "endtime";
    final String MINMAG_PARAM = "minmag";
    final String LIMIT_PARAM = "limit";
    final String format = "geojson";
    final String order = sortby;
    String start = startTime+"-01-01";
    String end = startTime+"-12-31";
    String minmag = maglevel;
    final String limit = "10";

    Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
            .appendQueryParameter(ORDER_PARAM, order)
            .appendQueryParameter(START_PARAM, start)
            .appendQueryParameter(END_PARAM, end)
            .appendQueryParameter(MINMAG_PARAM, minmag)
            .appendQueryParameter(LIMIT_PARAM, limit)
            .build();
    String url = buildUri.toString();

    // Don't perform the request if there are no URLs, or the first URL is null.
    if (url == null) {
    }
    earthquakeTask.execute(url);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    updateEarthquake();
}

/**
 * {@link AsyncTask} to perform the network request on a background thread, and then
 * update the UI with the list of earthquakes in the response.
 *
 * AsyncTask has three generic parameters: the input type, a type used for progress updates, and
 * an output type. Our task will take a String URL, and return an Earthquake. We won't do
 * progress updates, so the second generic is just Void.
 *
 * We'll only override two of the methods of AsyncTask: doInBackground() and onPostExecute().
 * The doInBackground() method runs on a background thread, so it can run long-running code
 * (like network activity), without interfering with the responsiveness of the app.
 * Then onPostExecute() is passed the result of doInBackground() method, but runs on the
 * UI thread, so it can use the produced data to update the UI.
 */
private class EarthquakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<EarthquakeInfo>> {

    /**
     * This method runs on a background thread and performs the network request.
     * We should not update the UI from a background thread, so we return a list of
     * {@link EarthquakeInfo}s as the result.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<EarthquakeInfo> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        List<EarthquakeInfo> result = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0]);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * This method runs on the main UI thread after the background work has been
     * completed. This method receives as input, the return value from the doInBackground()
     * method. First we clear out the adapter, to get rid of earthquake data from a previous
     * query to USGS. Then we update the adapter with the new list of earthquakes,
     * which will trigger the ListView to re-populate its list items.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<EarthquakeInfo> data) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        eAdapter.clear();
        // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            eAdapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my Setting Activity code

```
public class SettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity
    implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener{

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_mag_key)));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.start_key)));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.sort_key)));

}

private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));

}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    String stringValue = newValue.toString();
    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference preferences = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = preferences.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(preferences.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }else {
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Hope that it can help any others who are facing the same problem. Please also advise if there are any "bad reason" to fetch the data in onResume.

Thanks all of your reply !!!!!!